# $a\cdot b\cdot c = 60$, What is the maximum value of $a + b + c$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, integers, maxima-minima

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers with different numbers.

$a\cdot b\cdot c = 60$

What is the maximum value of $a+b+c$?

I'm trying to find the best method to solve this question. What are the methods we might use? Also, trial and error seems a bit useless for this question.

Comment: $60=2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ so there aren't so many combinations to try ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Contains $1$ twice... So many incorrect answer attempts here...

Comment: @Lagranian It's alarming how wrong answers are downvoted straight away. Come on, give these people some time to check their post!

Comment: @TobyMak What's wrong with downvoting incorrect answers? Then what are downvotes for? If a user checks their post and corrects their mistake I will undo my downvote of course.

Comment: @orlp My point isn't that people shouldn't downvote, but people should not downvote a bad answer straight away.

Comment: @TobyMak That's silly, a post is in some state, and either deserves or does not deserve a downvote in that state. Time is irrelevant. If you need more time to edit and check your post, wait longer before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to solve this is to factorize $60$ giving $2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

Now it should be fairly obvious that if we want to maximize the sum we want to group the biggest factors together. The best way to do this is just distributing the smallest factors (after $1$) into all but one of the variables, and clumping all the biggest ones into just one:

$$a = 1$$
$$b = 2$$
$$c = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 30$$

Giving maximum sum $33$.

---

In general an algorithm for splitting up a number $n$ into $k$ different variables with the greatest sum is to repeatedly assign the smallest divisor $d$ of $n$ not assigned before to a variable, and continuing with $n/d$ and $k-1$ variables.

Comment: What if we have been asked for minimum value? Can we apply the same solution?

Comment: @Lagranian No, minimum value is more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a>b>c$.

Now, $a\leq30$ because if $a>30$ then $a=60$, which gives $b=c=1$, which is impossible.

Since $f(x)=e^x$ is a convex function and
$$(\ln30,\ln2,\ln1)\succ(\ln{a},\ln{b},\ln{c}),$$
by Karamata we obtain:
$$a+b+c=e^{\ln{a}}+b^{\ln{b}}+c^{\ln{c}}\leq e^{\ln30}+e^{\ln2}+e^{\ln1}=33.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b,c)=(30,2,1)$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Done!

The minimal value of $a+b+c$ we can get by AM-GM.

Indeed, $$a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3\sqrt[3]{60}=11.7...,$$
which says that $$a+b+c\geq12.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b,c)=(5,4,3)$, which says that $12$ is a minimal value.

Comment: You are great ;) If you can show the minimal value too, I'd be happy.

Comment: Also, I couldn't get this step: $a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{60}=11.7...\geq12.$ Where did you find the $\geq3\sqrt[3]{60}$ from?

Comment: I used AM-GM: $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}.$

Comment: However, I don't know what it means. Our teacher didn't show it. I only know the squares which is like $\sqrt {2}$ or $2\sqrt {3}$.

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means I am ready to prove it if you want.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: Also I didn't know what karamata inequaility is.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality

Comment: I don't get it by wikipedia. Your answer is too high for me.

Comment: Try to draw the graph of the convex function $f(x)=e^x$ and read about $(a_1,b_1,c_1)\succ(a_2,b_2,c_2)$. It's obvious enough.

Comment: You are right but I don't know the convex function.

Comment: Also what do you mean by $\text {In}$?

Comment: $\ln{x}=\log_ex$, where $e=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=2.718281828459045...$

Comment: If you be more clear at this step $(\ln30,\ln2,\ln1)\succ(\ln{a},\ln{b},\ln{c})$ I might be getting it. First time I've seen this symbol $\succ$

Comment: It means $\ln30\geq\ln{a}$, $\ln30+\ln2\geq\ln{a}+\ln{b}$ and $\ln30+\ln2+\ln1=\ln{a}+\ln{b}+\ln{c}.$

Comment: Wow, I'm so confused right now :/

Comment: Can you make your answer simpler? It seems too high for me.

Comment: My solution is general, but you can get all $a$, $b$ and $c$ directly: $(a,b,c)\in\{(30,2,1),(15,4,1),(12,5,1),(10,3,2),(10,6,1),(6,5,2), (5,4,3)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us focus on the property that $a,b,c$ are all integers which are different from each other.

We realise that to make $c$ as large as possible, $a$ and $b$ have to be as small as possible to satisfy $a \cdot b \cdot c = 60$. To do this, we let $a=1$, and $b$ to be the next largest factor $2$. From this, $c=30$.

Therefore, $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=30$, which has the sum $33$.

This strategy, along with @orlp's only works when the numbers are all integers. Otherwise, we could set $a$ and $b$ as close to $0$ as we want, and $c$ will just keep getting larger and larger.

Comment: Don't be so quick to judge. People make mistakes all the time, and I need some time to check my post first for any mistakes.